# Error after upgrade to 4.7.1 "Call to undefined method CRM_Utils_System::isUserLoggedIn" (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, error

I've just upgraded from 4.5.2 to 4.7.1 and everything seemed to be working OK. I was able to use the system fine for an hour or so.

Then I was trying to re-assign some transactions from one user to another using PHPMyAdmin (by changing the contact id--I've done this before without problems) and suddenly I get a 500 Server error and nothing works.

Looking in the logs I find:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   CRM_Utils_System::isUserLoggedIn() in
>   /var/www/vhosts//httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/UFMatch.php on line 98

I also can see some references to:

> Call to undefined method CRM_Utils_System::getUFLocale()

I can't see how a change in data can have caused this??

I re-imported the db (back to the 4.5.2 version) but I still can't access anything--I can't even run the upgrade script.

I put a clean install of the 4.7.1 plugin code and that's not fixed it either.

I'm stuck, it works fine on the test system but is totally broken on my live system now.

Thanks

**Update 9th Feb:**

I'm running:
PHP Version 5.3.25
MySQL Version: 5.5.32
Unfortunately because it's a shared hosted system, I'm not sure I can get the version of PHP updated.

Comment: I'm looking on my phone so might be wrong, but what i see is that https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Utils/System.php doesn't have CRM_Utils_System::isUserLoggedIn() but https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Core/BAO/UFMatch.php calls it several times. If that's right, this looks like an issue worth reporting.

Comment: May be entirely unrelated, but David Christie had to set up a settings_location.php to get WP working with 4.7.1: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9361/problem-with-upgrade-to-4-7-0-wordpress-4-4-2

Comment: Seems like the change in [091db90](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/091db9085e779dc6b50f1644c721846437b6c844) has moved these methods to being called via [`__callStatic`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php). For some reason this isn't happening on your site. Could you update your question and tell us what PHP version you're using?

Answer (score 1):

A few possibilities:

You may have an old version of the file **customised**. Check in your custom PHP folder, or do a find on the name of the file that contains CRM_Utils_System::isUserLoggedIn to see if this is a possibility. You may need to update it to match the newer version of the file, while keeping your change (a consultant will happily help you here if it gets tricky - either myself john@civifirst.com or a partner organisation https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors).

Alternatively, are your resources and URLs **set correctly** in your administer tab?

Failing all of those, double check the site's URL in your **civicrm.settings.php** file.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Does the method CRM_Utils_System::isUserLoggedIn() exist in the files? i.e. CRM/Utils/System.php have a method isUserLoggedIn()? Seems more like a code issue than a data issue.

Comment: Yes it does. In CRM > Utils > System there's a Base class and then custom classes for the different environments, e.g. WordPress.php. So I did wonder if somehow it couldn't work out it was a WordPress system and therefore not loading the right file. But I've no idea why that might suddenly start happening when it was working OK before.